# class declaration in IPhone SDk?import/class?

Tags: class, import

I got three viewcontrollers.  --> AViewController,BViewController,CViewController

And AViewController is the main page to navigate to each of them. But all of them need to access each others properties. As in they need to create a object of the other controller in their viewcontroller. BViewController is in charge of changing the label1 text in AViewController. CViewController is in charge of changing the label2 text in AViewController. AViewController use presentModalController: to switch to BViewController and CViewController.

there is error doing so.  Why?
Is there anything to do with the @class or #import?? 
 Where should the @class and #import should put in, is it in the .h or .m?can show me? 
i am very confused.

Anyone can help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is a bad idea to tightly couple classes together in the way that you're trying to do. Instead, create another class, say `ViewControllerManager`. This class can then instantiate all the view controller classes and pass properties of one class to another. The manager must also be responsible for the life time and scope of all view controller classes.

Comment: But if ViewControllerManager class are use to instantiate all the view controller classes and pass properties of one class to another. All the other classes also need to access the ViewControllerManager class, am i right? they still have to put #import or  @class within their classes. Sorry if i am wrong in the concept. i am a noob. please correct with code if possible.

Comment: But if i want to stick with what i have stated above. how to i solve it?the problem is it the #import and @class stuff? where should i put them into?can show me some short sample code as in their .h and .m included which one? thank you and thank you for your reply too.

Comment: The view controller classes need not be aware of the manager class. Only the manager class need to know all the controller classes. I'm sorry, but I cannot help you with the code as I'm not familiar with iPhone development.

Comment: hmm..ok. superman really thank you so much .but i hope i can find out the problem behind it and understand how to use the #import and @class if it is the problem.

Comment: And thank you for all the viewers who view this post. Hope there's people out there who can help me. thank you. and will be appreciate.